# How to make a linear layout stick to an ImageView in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a guitar fret board image and have dots that I have overlay-ed on top of them. Unfortunately when I scroll the image the dots don't move with it. Sorry it is so long. It's the only way I could figure out how to implement dots on the image. If anyone has any ideas on a better way to do the images also, I'm all ears.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fretboardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="67dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/fretboard" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="61dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="44dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot1e"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2.5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="44dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot1B"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2.5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="44dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot1G"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="44dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot1D"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="44dp" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot1A"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="44dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot1E"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="19dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot2e"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2.5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot2B"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2.5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot2G"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot2D"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot2A"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot2E"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="19dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot3e"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2.5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot3B"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2.5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot3G"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot3D"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot3A"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot3E"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="19dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot4e"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2.5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot4B"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2.5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot4G"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot4D"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot4A"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot4E"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="19dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot5e"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2.5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot5B"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2.5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot5G"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot5D"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot5A"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot5E"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="19dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot6e"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2.5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot6B"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2.5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot6G"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot6D"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot6A"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot6E"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="19dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot7e"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2.5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot7B"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2.5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot7G"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot7D"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot7A"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot7E"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="21dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot8e"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2.5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot8B"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2.5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot8G"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot8D"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot8A"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot8E"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="17dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot9e"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2.5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot9B"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2.5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot9G"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot9D"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot9A"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot9E"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="18dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot10e"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2.5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot10B"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2.5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot10G"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot10D"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot10A"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot10E"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />


    </LinearLayout>


   </LinearLayout>


   </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: you'd 2 nested views to the `FrameLayout`; they should be only one

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, could you explain further?

Comment: Hi Jack, your root element in the layout is `FrameLayout`, and it has two directly nested child elements, an `ImageView` and a `LinearLayout`, as per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout), the `FrameLayout` should only have one direct nested (child) `View`

Comment: Ok. Thank you for clarifying but how do I keep my image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'd place all the buttons in the layout, and put it into a ScrollView.
This way, you can give the fragment a background image, and scroll everything together.

Like this:

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/your_image" <!-- place that image in the drawables folder -->
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

(Mind that you'll have to put the scroll view inside some layout as well, for example a constraint layout)

You can also set the background image programmatically with:

```
LinearLayout mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout1);
mLayout.setBackground(Image);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 I also found this works too.

 public LinearLayout mainLayout;
 mainLayout = root.findViewById(R.id.fretboardLayout);



   @Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
{

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
    {
        getAccelerometer(event);
    }

}


  private void getAccelerometer(SensorEvent event)
{
    float[] values = event.values;
    // Movement
    float x = values[0];
    float y = values[1];
    float z = values[2];

    final int acceleration = maxX / bitmapWidth * 2;


    float accelerationSquareRoot = (x * x + y * y + z * z)
            / (SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH * SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH);
    long actualTime = event.timestamp;

    /*
    if( Math.abs(scrollIndex) > 2) // if scroll amount is too much override it and set it to 0
    {
        x = 0;
    }

     */

    scrollIndex += x;

  

    fretboardView.scrollBy( (int) x * (int) accelerationSquareRoot * acceleration, 0);

 
    if (accelerationSquareRoot >= 2) 
    {
        if (actualTime - lastUpdate < 200) 
        {
            return;
        }
        lastUpdate = actualTime;

    }
    
}
```